# Dev Tools call stack with source files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools

I'm trying to trace function calls from a button click in a react app. I've set some breakpoints in the interesting parts from the network call stack that the button click initiated. As I follow the call stack down looking for the initiating function I am seeing typescript files which seem to call into the compiled minified app js file. Obviously, the ts file must be displayed using some source mapping magic as it cannot be used by the browser. I am assuming that the ts file has been compiled into the minified react app js, but how do I find that? The call stack from the ts file flows into a network call function in the minified app js but where is the ts file code really coming from?

TLDR: Where can I find the js that the ts has been compiled into using dev tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Sources panel, open the ts file. If there are sourcemaps, you can see in the bottom corner right tells you where the actual js file is. https://coffee-cart.netlify.app/

[image: Which JS file it is from]